# Bind Alt-N to Nth window in byobu/screen

Tags: shortcut-keys, screen, byobu

I've been trying to bind a shortcut to switching to a specific window in Byobu, but I'm not having success. I wanted to bind Alt-(screen's number) but it's not working. I think I'm using the wrong ASCII codes.

Take <kbd>Alt + 1</kbd> for example: I've tried using the lines

```
bind \078 select 1
```

and

```
bind \78 select 1
```

to both `~/.screeenrc` and `~/.config/byobu/keybindings`, but neither worked.

Am I using the wrong code, or is there no standard ASCII code for <kbd>Alt + 1</kbd>?

Comment: I'm not sure about making new bindings, but just to check: do you know you can do ctrl+a then hit the number for the window you want?

Comment: @maco Yes, I just like how convenient M-1 feels for me. Besides, I removed C-a because I'm just too used to emacs shortcuts, and I kept hitting it while trying to move back. I'm still considering reactivating it, but I do a lot of writing on emacs and I don't think my brain can handle both at the same time. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check what octal code is generated when you press alt+1, type in the following:

```
echo -n C-qM-1 | od -t o1
```

(If that makes no sense to you: instead of writing C-q, press ctrl-q and for M-1 substitute alt-1, and some character should show up). For example, I have Finnish keyboard and en_US.UTF-8 locale and get:

```
0000000 302 261
```

so I put in my .screenrc:

```
bindkey "\302\261" select 1
```

**Note**: by default this will not work in a gnome-terminal at all, since alt+number changes the tab and screen (or bash) doesn't get a chance to see the keypress. Go to `Edit > Keyboards Shortcuts...` to change the shortcuts.

Comment: This method for inserting M-1 isn't working for me. If I press C-q the system just ignores it, and anything I press later just gets interpreted regularly (M-1 gives me an `arg: 1`). I thought it my be the gnome-terminal, but I switched to the console (Ctrl-Alt-F2) and the same thing happened.

Comment: Ok, try it in xterm. Seems to work better.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Using the code the shortcut now works, but only if byobu is running in xterm, otherwise it just gives me that `(arg: 1)`. But I'll look into it later, thanks for the help.

Comment: You can unbind all of the alt+n keymappings with the bash builtin bind, like this: `for i in $(seq 0 9) ; do bind -r "\e${i}" ; done`