# Shift+F2 is ignored when using byobu with PuTTY (Windows 7)

Tags: putty, byobu

Connecting to byobu in Ubuntu 12.04.1 (precise) from PuTTY on a Windows 7 system, when I type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to get a vertical split, nothing happens. Typing plain <kbd>F2</kbd> works and opens a new window.

I tried all the terminal keyboard types in PuTTY configuration (ex. XTerm R2, Linux) without any luck. Any ideas? Is there nay another keyboard shortcut to do the same thing?

Comment: This isn't an ubuntu issue. Windows is likely capturing the key-combination and not sending it. Try to look at Windows / Putty documentation to see (a) how to stop Windows / putty from capturing the key-combination. Alternatively, there may be menu item to send the shift modifier in putty or look into remapping the key via input.rc (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/inputrc-tab-not-behaving-as-expected) or byobu itself (http://askubuntu.com/questions/51776/bind-alt-n-to-nth-window-in-byobu-screen)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Putty 0.73 on windows 10 (1903) connecting to Ubuntu 18.04 and byobu 5.125 and tmux 2.6.

I set Putty->Terminal->Keyboard->"Function keys and keypad" to Xterm R6.  This solves some problems but not the Shift-F2 issue.

Can't find any further method of changing Putty key bindings.

I'll investigate changing byobu key bindings.  Any other help on using Putty with Ubuntu and byobu?

Comment: Anything found new? Here i made bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/1882373 and here is author answering question so need to get him into contact https://askubuntu.com/questions/146585/how-do-i-make-the-f-keys-work-in-byobu-for-midnight-commander-mc-htop-etc